# Changing background colour with drop down menu

Tags: html

I am doing some uni work and I am stuck on this bit of code. I have to change the background colour of the page using a drop down menu.

Drop down menu code

```
 <form>
    Background colour:
    <select id= background>
     <option value="White"> White </option>
     <option value="Green" > Green</option>
     <option value="Black"> Black </option>



</select>
```

if statement

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var sel1 = document.getElementId('background')

if(sel1 =="Green"){

document.body.style.backgroundColor = Green

}
}
</script>
```

Also here is the button that runs the function

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Change Background</button>
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes.. document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";

Comment: Fixed it but still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your javascript code 
"getElementId" function is wrong.

Please try below code

```
function myFunction() {
    var sel1 = document.getElementById('background').value;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = sel1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To point out your mistakes:

- The `id` attribute of your `<select>` is missing quotes.
- The `getElementId` function should be `getElementById`.

You need a proper JavaScript function to handle the actual change, which can be triggered by either click of a button or by the change event in the dropdown itself. I have written a snippet using the latter method, but you can fetch the `selectElem` from inside the function using either `document.getElementById('background')` or the modern `document.querySelector('#background')` if you are required to use a button.

If you use a valid CSS value for `background-color` in the `value` attributes of your `<option>`s, you can use that value without complex `switch` or `if` statements.

The `this` bit in our function call refers to the calling HTML element.

```js
function updateBackgroundColour(selectElem) {
  var i = selectElem.selectedIndex; // Get the selected option's index.
  if (i < 0) {
    return; // Nothing is selected.
  }
  // Set the background-color CSS attribute of the <body> element to 
  // the value attribute of the selected option in our <select> element.
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectElem.options[i].value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Background color:
  <!-- Note the onchange attribute. "this" refers to the changing element. -->
  <select id="background" onchange="updateBackgroundColour(this)">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="MediumSpringGreen">Medium Spring Green</option>
    <option value="#34495e">Wet asphalt</option>
  </select>
<form>
```

Comment: Thank you do you know what I would need to change to change the text color instead

Comment: The text color of a element depends on the `color` CSS value. So in `<div style="color:red;"><p>Hello</p></div>` the "Hello" is in red, but in `<div style="color:red;"><p style="color:green;">Hello</p></div>` it is in green.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sel1 = document.getElementId('background').value;

  if(sel1 =="Green"){

      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "Green" ;

   }
 }
```

And this should be your html

```
<select id="background" onchange="myFunction() ">
```

Comment: Ive added that to the form but still no change I also have a button                                <button onclick="myFunction()">Change Background</button>

Answer (score -1):

Simply edit a jQuery script to display a GIF when you click on the dropdown and change the value of background image.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and telling someone to "simply edit a script" isn't specific or helpful advice. Also there is no need to bring jQuery into this when it is not in the project. :)